# How can I allow sticky posts but cap the query to 1 post?

Tags: wp-query, filters, sticky-post

I have a partial that I call around the website at various points.  This partial simply displays the latest Post.

It looks like so:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'order'             => 'desc'
);
query_posts($args);

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
            $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'home-news-thumbnail' );
        }
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3></a>
        <?php if(!empty($featured_image)): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $featured_image[0]; ?>" alt="" width="250" class="pull-left">
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
        </p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-brand-dark">more</a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

This works fine until I 'Sticky' a post.  Then I get 2 posts instead of 1.

How can I amend all queries so that `posts_per_page` has the requested number of posts, regardless of sticky posts?

So in the example above, I'm currently getting **2** posts (despite requesting 1), but I want the latest post, whether that's a sticky post or not.

I know about `ignore_sticky_posts` parameter, but that will ignore the sticky post, which I don't want to do.  If there's a sticky post it should be first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to force the exact `posts_per_page` value in `WP_Query`, regardless of sticky posts or custom post injects:

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page'        => 1,
    '_exact_posts_per_page' => true   // <-- our custom input argument
];
```

by using our custom `_exact_posts_per_page` input argument.

I'm sure this has been implemented many times before, but I didn't find it at the moment, so let us try to implement it with this demo plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 *  Plugin Name:   Exact Posts Per Pages 
 *  Description:   Activated through the '_exact_posts_per_page' bool argument of WP_Query 
 *  Plugin URI:    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/257523/26350 
 */

add_filter( 'the_posts', function( $posts, \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( 
        wp_validate_boolean( $q->get( '_exact_posts_per_page' ) )
        && ! empty( $posts ) 
        && is_int( $q->get( 'posts_per_page' ) ) 
    )
        $posts = array_slice( $posts, 0, absint( $q->get( 'posts_per_page' ) ) );

    return $posts;

}, 999, 2 ); // <-- some late priority here!
```

Here we use the `the_posts` filter to slice the array, no matter if it contains sticky posts or not.

The `the_posts` filter is not applied if the `suppress_filters` input argument of `WP_Query` is `true`.

**Note** that `query_posts()` is not recommended in plugins or themes. Check out the many warnings in the *Code reference* [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/).

Hope you can test it further and adjust to your needs!

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I find it strange this isn't default behaviour

Comment: In the core code it can be seen pagination is not honored for sticky posts, they go to the top regardless. And well that is the idea behind the status 'sticky'

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you want your query to ignore if a post is sticky and dont have it at the top of your ordered query:</strike>

```
//$args = array(
//    'posts_per_page' => 1,
//    'order'          => 'desc'
//    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 //set this
//);
```

<strike>with this the sticky posts will not be ignored, what will be ignored is their status of `sticky`, the sticky posts will still be in your result, what `'ignore_sticky_posts'` does is tell the query to not bring the posts that are sticky to the top if you are ordering them.</strike>

**EDIT**:

If you want just 1, remove the While loop logic:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'order'             => 'desc'
);
query_posts($args);

if ( have_posts() ) :

        if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
            $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'home-news-thumbnail' );
        }
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3></a>
        <?php if(!empty($featured_image)): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $featured_image[0]; ?>" alt="" width="250" class="pull-left">
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
        </p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-brand-dark">more</a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

you can even remove the `'posts_per_page' => 1` the output will be the first one.

Comment: I don't want to ignore it at all.  I want the sticky post.  I just don't want it along with another post.  I'm asking for 1 post currently and getting 2.

Comment: @mikemike: his answer is correct, the "ignore" in 'ignore_sticky_posts' simply means "ignore the special processing of sticky posts" (i.e., don't automatically move stickies to the front), see [WP_Query, Pagination Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

Comment: But I want it at the front...

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron I've updated the question to be more clear. I just want the latest post, whether that is sticky or not.  Limiting number of posts to 1 currently gives me 2 posts, which is obviously unexpected, and setting `ignore_sticky_posts` will hide the sticky one, but I _want_ the sticky posts, just not more than I'm asking for

Comment: oh i got it now

Comment: Your original question was clear enough, and the original answer given by @DavidLee is still correct.  See [Lines 2966-2979](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2966) of the source for `WP_Query`.  Without `ignore_sticky_posts' => true`, any sticky posts that were **not included** in the original results are fetched and prepended to those results, resulting in more posts than `posts_per_page` would suggest.  So, if you have 20 sticky posts, without `ignore_sticky_posts => true`, you will get _at least_ 20 posts in your results.

Comment: You're missing the point. I want sticky posts included, I just want the additional posts removed. Using this answer I see 1 post, but it isn't the sticky one

Comment: Thanks @DavidLee - not having the loop achieves it for this one partial but it's a little un-elegant.  The query is still pulling in more posts than it needs to, and I ideally wanted to do this site-wide rather than having to amend every loop around the website.

Answer (score 0):

Try using if(! is_sticky())

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'order'             => 'desc'
);
query_posts($args);

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if(! is_sticky()) {
        if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
            $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'home-news-thumbnail' );
        }
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3></a>
        <?php if(!empty($featured_image)): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $featured_image[0]; ?>" alt="" width="250" class="pull-left">
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
        </p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-brand-dark">more</a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php } 
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Please note, this will completely prevent any sticky posts from appearing.

Comment: I want sticky posts, but just 1 in this case. I also wanted a global method (using a filter), this is just an illustration

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed your comment that you wanted to accomplish this via a filter, so
here you go (this basically expounds on the comments I've made on your original question and [@DavidLee's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257403/how-can-i-allow-sticky-posts-but-cap-the-query-to-1-post/#257404)).

The following will result in 1 and only 1 post, regardless of stickies.
If the most recently published post **is** sticky, you will get it.  If the most recently
published post **is not** sticky, you will *still* get it.  And, you will get no other
posts, sticky or otherwise.

```
add_filter ('pre_get_posts', 'get_only_one_post') ;

function
get_only_one_post ($wp_query)
{
    if (is_admin () || !$wp_query->is_main_query ()) {
        // we're not in the Main Loop, so return the query unmodified
        return ($wp_query) ;
        }

    // order by most recently published 1st
    // this isn't really necesary (since it is the default),
    // but include it just in case some other filter has modified that default
    $wp_query->set ('orderby', 'date') ;
    $wp_query->set ('order', 'DESC') ;

    // limit to 1 post, not counting stickies
    $wp_query->set ('posts_per_page', 1) ;

    // disable the special processing of sticky posts.
    // without this, ALL sticky posts will be returned, whether they match
    // the rest of the query_vars or not
    $wp_query->set ('ignore_sticky_posts', true) ;

    return ($wp_query) ;
}
```

## Explanation

### Without `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true`

The following is done:

> 1. retrieve posts according to query vars, including respecting `posts_per_page` and `orderby`
>
>    - any sticky posts that match query vars will already be included in the results
> 2. move sticky posts that are included in the results to the front of the list
> 3. retreive **all** sticky posts
>
>    1. those not already in the results are preprend to the list
>
>       - it is this step that potentially causes the results to contain more than `posts_per_page` posts being returned
>       - See [Lines 2966-2979, of the source for WP_Query](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2966)

### With `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true`

The following is done:

> 1. retrieve posts according to query vars, including respecting `posts_per_page` and `orderby`
>
>    - any sticky posts that match query vars will already be included in the results

## Edit: Additional answer

OK, try this:

```
add_filter ('pre_get_posts', 'set_posts_per_page_on_front_end_main_query') ;
add_filter ('the_posts', 'respect_posts_per_page') ;

function
respect_posts_per_page ($posts, $wp_query)
{
    return (array_slice ($posts, 0, $wp_query->get ('posts_per_page', count ($posts)))) ;
}

function
set_posts_per_page_on_front_end_main_query ($wp_query)
{
    if ( is_admin () || !$wp_query->is_main_query ()) {
        return ($wp_query) ;
        }

    $wp_query->set ('posts_per_page', 1) ;

    return ($wp_query) ;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to remove sticky posts. I just want the number I'm asking for returned. I'm asking for 1 post, so I want the latest post, or if the are sticky posts the latest sticky post.